# Console Application with C# Not Displaying WriteLine if Bool is True

Tags: c#, console-application

I am just starting to learn C# as my first programming language, so I decided to make a simple question and answer C# console application. The console will ask you a question, and if you get it right it will say "Correct". After a while I got it all to work with no errors, except it never said "Correct"

```
using System;
namespace Project
{
  class MainClass
  {
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
      byte answer = 0;
      Console.WriteLine ("What is 27+4?");
      Console.ReadLine ();
      if (answer == 31) 
      {
        bool answerCorrect = true;
        if (answerCorrect == true)
          Console.WriteLine ("Correct!");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

Because `Console.ReadLine()` reads your input(as a string), but it's not assigned to your variable `answer`. To make your program work, change the line to:

```
answer = byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

But remember to improve your code, for example, using `int` instead of `byte`, and the code in `if (answer == 31)` block can be shorter, etc. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You must store the string return value from ReadLine and parse that. Like so:

```
    byte answer = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("What is 27+4?");
    string s = Console.ReadLine();

    if (byte.TryParse(s, out answer) && answer == 31)
    {
        bool answerCorrect = true;
        if (answerCorrect == true)
            Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
using System;

namespace Project
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            byte answer = 0;
            Console.WriteLine ("What is 27+4?");
            answer = byte.Parse(Console.ReadLine ());
            if (answer == 31) 
            {
                bool answerCorrect = true;
                    if (answerCorrect == true)
                        Console.WriteLine ("Correct!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Console.Readline()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the string value entered by the user, so firstly capture that input.

`string input = Console.ReadLine ();`

Next check if the input is correct by using [String.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx(v=vs.110).aspx) method to compare

`if(input.Equals("31"))`

and lastly there's no need to create and assign a value to an `answerCorrect` variable since if the code goes into the `if` statement the answer is correct, so just `Console.WriteLine ("Correct!")` inside.

Answer (score 0):

First I would use `int` instead of `byte`. Then you have to assign the userinput to your variable `answer`. The type `int` provides a method called `.Parse(string s)` which tries to convert the string you get from `Console.ReadLine()` to an int. Of course it fails if the input is something like `"hello"`. That's a good thing to look at to improve later.
Your use of `bool answerCorrect` may be correct, but remember: the comparison always "returns" a bool, so you don't really need an extra one.
Lastly, you're missing one important line `Console.Read();` at the very end in your `main`-method. It's a bit cheaty but your program then waits for a userinput and the console window stays open and you can actually see what's in there.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int answer = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("What is 27 + 4?");
    answer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    if (answer == 31)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
    }
    else //I added this part for beauty reasons
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect!");
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

I recommend you to have a look at `while` to run your program as long as the user gives the wrong answer and `try..catch` to accept `"hello"` as an input but handle it differently, to improve even more.
Good job though for your first C# application.